# How to specify which folder new Outlook AppointmentItems are created in?

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm creating `AppointmentItem` objects for outlook with the following code:

```
AppointmentItem apt = (APPointmentItem)OLApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
// set parameters for 'apt', like body, subject etc.
// ...
apt.Save();
```

I have the name of a calendar I want to put this event in, but I can't figure out how to specify which folder the newly created event should go in to. New events always seem to appear in the main calendar folder.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Kudos to Eugene Astafiev for providing it at http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/

So the above code should be:

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    Application outlookApplication = new Application();
    MAPIFolder customer_folder = GetMyFolder(path, outlookApplication.Session.Folders);  //function to get your folder
    AppointmentItem apt = (AppointmentItem)customer_folder.Items.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
    // set parameters for 'apt', like body, subject etc.
    // ...
    apt.Save();
```

And here is the code for `GetMyFolder` to recursively find your custom folder:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    private MAPIFolder _mapiFolder;

    private MAPIFolder GetMyFolder(string path, IEnumerable folders)
    {
        if (!path.StartsWith(@"\\", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return null;

        string pathRoot = GetFolderPathRoot(path);

        foreach (Folder folder in folders.Cast<Folder>().TakeWhile(
            folder => _mapiFolder == null).Select(
                folder => new { folder, folderRoot = GetFolderPathRoot(folder.FolderPath) }).Where(
                    folder => folder.folderRoot == pathRoot).Select(folder => folder.folder))
        {
            if (folder.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olAppointmentItem && folder.FolderPath == path)
            {
                s_mapiFolder = folder;
                break;
            }

            if (folder.Folders.Cast<Folder>().Any())
                GetMapiFolder(false, folder.Folders, path);
        }

        return _mapiFolder;
    }

    private static string GetFolderPathRoot(string folderPath)
    {
        // Strip header directory seperator characters
        folderPath = folderPath.Remove(0, 2);

        // Find the index of a directory seperator character
        int index = folderPath.IndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 0);

        // Reconstruct the root path according to the index found
        return String.Format(@"\\{0}", index > 0 ? folderPath.Substring(0, index) : folderPath);
    }
```

**EDIT:** Revised code to recursively search only in folders under the specified path root.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is get access to the folder, then call folder.items.add and add you item.  It should look something like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder customer_folder = GetMyFolder();  //function to get your folder
AppointmentItem apt = (APPointmentItem)OLApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
// set parameters for 'apt', like body, subject etc.
// ...
apt.Save();
customer_folder.Items.Add(apt);
```

Comment: When I try this I get an exception: "Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid".

Any ideas?

Comment: ...Further; MAPIFolder::Items is a read-only property, which is probably why it's complaining about me trying to add something to it.

Comment: brendan, your code seems to be not functional. Maybe you could rewrite it to that it works? Would be great! Thanks.